# maven scm does not listen to perforce trigger output

Tags: maven, maven-3, perforce, maven-scm, maven-scm-plugin

Hello Maven / Perforce Experts,

I am trying to implement auto versioning of the maven artifacts for a project that uses Perforce as VCS.  That made me choose maven-scm-plugin and maven-release-plugin to achieve my purpose. 
We use triggers in perforce, which checks for violations in the xml content for each commit.

```
    checkstyle_xml change-content //depot/project/....xml " /p4/triggers/checkstyle-trigger.pl %user% %changelist% /p4"
```

Unfortunately, when I run the command “mvn -X -e -B scm:edit release:update-versions scm:checkin“ to edit the file, update the version and submit to perforce, maven does NOT honor the result from the perforce trigger and fails the build. However, as you can see the change is submitted to perforce eventually.

STACK TRACE USING XML WHICH HAS TRIGGER ENABLED

```
[DEBUG] Sending changelist:
Change: new

Description:
    Auto increment pom version during build process. Reviewed by: RE

Files:
    //depot/project/pom.xml

[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] Unable to submit
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] Debug: starting trigger script  
Change 351157 submitted.

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.112s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Oct 30 14:51:51 PDT 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 23M/219M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-scm-plugin:1.7:checkin (default-cli) on project phoenix: Command failed.Unable to submit -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal     org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-scm-plugin:1.7:checkin (default-cli) on project phoenix: Command failed.Unable to submit
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Command failed.Unable to submit
    at org.apache.maven.scm.plugin.AbstractScmMojo.checkResult(AbstractScmMojo.java:439)
    at org.apache.maven.scm.plugin.CheckinMojo.execute(CheckinMojo.java:83)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

I submitted the file locally to ensure perforce trigger doesn’t spit a failure status code and it actually returns SUCCESS too.
I am not sure why maven wont honor the perforce triggers.

```
p4 –u testuser submit -d "Test" pom.xml 
Submitting change 351166.
Locking 1 files ...
edit //depot/project/pom.xml#25
Debug: starting trigger script  
Change 351166 submitted.

$ echo $?
0
```

I tested a scenario with a txt file which doesn’t have perforce trigger enabled and maven returns build result as SUCCESS, because technically it doesn’t go through a perforce trigger

STACK TRACE USING TXT WHICH DOESNT HAVE TRIGGER

```
[DEBUG] Sending changelist:
Change: new

Description:
    Auto increment pom version during build process. Reviewed by: RE

Files:
    //depot/phoenix/auto-increment-pom/pom.txt

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.998s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Oct 30 14:55:04 PDT 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 18M/216M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**QUESTION:**

1. Has anyone experienced this behavior with maven and how did you workaround?
2. Would you know if it is possible to disable perforce trigger for a particular file, so that perforce doesn’t even go through the trigger

Comment: The determination of which files activate which triggers is controlled by the "path" field in the triggers table (see 'p4 help triggers').

Comment: thanks.. that's right, however the trigger looks for any xml pattern and i am unfamiliar on how it is possible to exclude only pom.xml. I could do that within the trigger script, but i dont want perforce to even get to the point of executing the trigger script if it is pom.xml `checkstyle_xml change-content //depot/project/....xml " /p4/triggers/checkstyle-trigger.pl %user% %changelist% /p4"`

Comment: I posted an answer with more details on how to exclude a single file from a particular trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use exclusionary syntax (a leading hyphen in the path field) in your triggers table to specify that certain files or patterns are not to run the trigger.

There is an example of this in the 'p4 triggers' documentation: http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/p4_triggers.html

Be careful with this syntax, it's a little persnickety:

1. The triggers are grouped based on trigger name and type
2. The order of the lines in the trigger table for a group matters

There is also a knowledge base article for this feature that goes into some more detail: http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB_Article/Excluded-Trigger-Paths-Not-Being-Recognized

Comment: I tried the solution mentioned in the second block, however it appears to be wrong from the KNB. The 3rd block works like a charm.. Thank you so much for helping to move towards the right direction..